# Retain changed div text after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, refresh, retain

I was wondering the following, I am using the following code to change the value of a div.

```
$('#element').click(function() {
  $('div').html('Hi There');
});
```

However, when I refresh the page, the value returns to its original value, is there a way to retain the value after the refresh?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: cookies, local storage or serverside storage.

Comment: wait i provide you the answer in a minute without cookies, juzz by jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Local Storage or cookies or Session Storage to remember specific values even after page refresh.

this is client side implementation of your request by using local storage

```
<div id="mydiv">
    content
</div>
<input type="button" id="element" value="test" />
<div id="result">
</div>



<script>
function save_on_local_storage() { 

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("olddiv", $('div').html() );
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}

}

function get_local_storage() { 

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {

    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("olddiv");
} else {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}

}


$('#element').click(function() {
  save_on_local_storage();
  $('#mydiv').html('Hi There');
});

get_local_storage();
</script>
```

if you want to retain html content after click on element button simply you must call   `save_on_local_storage();` after `$('#mydiv').html('Hi There');`

here is fiddle try [link](http://jsfiddle.net/p7c2gwuc/2/)

Comment: It needs to be available for other who visit the website as well. I have no knowledge of HTML5 Local Storage, but I'm guessing this is not possible

Comment: please look at this example on w3schools [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: @Michael, you need a server side logic, to do that, you can use scripting languages like PHP, Python, Ruby, ASP.NET or at least some SSI (Server Side Includes). You cannot do this with client logic only (JavaScript), since its executed on client machine and will not be possible to share results across different visitors.

Comment: this is client side try with local stroage [link](http://jsfiddle.net/p7c2gwuc/1/)